# Eclipse: How can I delete "Installed Software" faster?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

I already know how to manually delete software from eclipse (**Help** -> **Installation details**). The problem is, I have to delete more than 20 of these, and eclipse has to restart every time a software is deleted. 
Is there a folder I could find the software in and delete them from? Or do I just have to do them one at a time?[image: Delete Software Window]

Answer (score 0):

You can hold down CTRL (or CMD if you're on Mac) and select multiple items before clicking Uninstall.

Comment: that doesn't work. I should've mentioned it in the question.